# Nothing gets added to Object list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of objects, where I only want to add a new object to it, if the list does not already contain an object with matching properties, here is how I am trying to do it:

```
reservation = new ForecastReservationAssignees();


string extractWeekNumber = Regex.Match(weekNumberValue.Value.ToString(), @"\d+").Value;

int weekNumber = Int32.Parse(extractWeekNumber);


if ((reservationAssigneeList.Any(i => i.AvailableFor != weekNumber))
    && (reservationAssigneeList.Any(i => i.EmployeeName != employeeNameValue.Value.ToString())))
{
    reservation.AvailableFor = weekNumber;


    // Add it.
    reservation.EmployeeName = employeeNameValue.Value.ToString();
    // Add object.
    reservationAssigneeList.Add(reservation);
}
```

First I create a new object, which has properties `EmployeeName`, a string and `AvailableFor` which is an int. I extract the number from a string i got elsewhere and parse the number to an int. Then comes the if statement. Here I want to check if the list already contains these properties. Essentially what I want is, to only add an employee a single time, and then that employee can have multiple `AvailableFor` which is weeks, although only the same week one time. So en xample would be:

```
> Employee1

Week 11

Week 12

Week 13
```

So no employee name twice, and no week twice for each employee. The weeks can be the same for multiple employees though, so first and second employee both have the same week.

When I run the above code, I get nothing, nothing gets added at all. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to debug to see if you enter the if block?

Comment: Break the IF statement into smaller pieces and find out which piece is failing.

Comment: Yes i have tried to debug, it does not go inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is incorrect:

`if ((reservationAssigneeList.Any(i => i.AvailableFor != weekNumber))
    && (reservationAssigneeList.Any(i => i.EmployeeName != employeeNameValue.Value.ToString())))`

You're saying if ANY item has AvailableFor not matching weekNumber, AND any item has an employee name that isn't equal to the employee name value.

You need to combine them.

`if ((reservationAssigneeList.Any(i => i.AvailableFor != weekNumber && i.EmployeeName != employeeNameValue.Value.ToString())))`

That way you'll only check each individual item to see if they match.

Comment: I tried your if statement but it does still not go inside the if statement, maybe I am doing something wrong elsewhere, i will get back. Thanks.

Comment: Okay for some reason if I did == instead of != and put ! at the start of the if statement it works.

Answer (score 2):

Doing two `.Any()` calls like you are will check the two independently, i.e. they don't have to be part of the same reservation.  Try this for your if statement

```
if (reservationAssigneeList.Any(i => (i.AvailableFor != weekNumber) && (i.EmployeeName != employeeNameValue.Value.ToString()) ) )
{
```

That should make it so the same reservation has to match not match on AvailableFor and EmployeeName

Comment: I tried your if statement but it does still not go inside the if statement, maybe I am doing something wrong elsewhere, i will get back. Thanks